# Java unicode characters - read and write

Tags: java

I am expecting something to be replaced when I delimit the string by \u0001.

**Note:** I have to write data to a text file and create a hive file out of it. Hive field delimiter is \u0001. So if I use the same delimiter to write the data to nfs file, it is blank. i.e no characters are there. So data is not reflecting in hive.

**Code to write to nfs:**

```
bw.write(StringUtils.join(str.toArray(), "\u0001"));
```

File contains data:
abcdefgh

I expect every character has to be delimited something like
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

List of string contains each character as an item.

Any suggestions?

**Complete code:**

```
package com.netapp.asup.hive.snappy;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Write {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(args[0])));
        List str = new ArrayList();
        str.add("a");
        str.add("b");

        bw.write(StringUtils.join(str.toArray(), "\u0001"));

        bw.close();
    }

}
```

I didn't use diamond operator due to java version 5.

Comment: Did you specify the character encoding of your 'bw' ? Why are you doing "toArray" and what is "str"?

Comment: @matt good point. I didnt specify. Please see the edits for the complete code

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do is to specify your encoding.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( 
                           new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(new File(args[0]),
                                Charset.forName("UTF-8")
                           )
                     );
```

Comment: I still see nothing between the characters. `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(args[0]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: @GopsAB what are you viewing it with? If you open it as a utf-8 encoded text file, then there should be 3 characters. \u0001 is a ctrl sequence. I don't know what you should see.

Comment: I understand. I expect to see ^A between them.

Comment: Did you try writing the string "a\u0001b"? Maybe the string utils does something. How are you viewing the file?